# C# - Return string from running winform app without exiting

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a working on a winform app which took arguments from cmd (or any other command sending program) at run time. I'm successful in getting args at run time but I've to return the status as a string from where the command was executed without exiting the app.

Lets say, I execute the php script like to give args to my running app like:

```
<?php
   $output = shell_exec('MyApp args');
   echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

Now, i want to return string value to $output variable. Is there any way to return the value from c# winform app.

Comment: When you run a process, it returns an exit code (int) not a string.  Or Maybe I don't get what you are asking....

Comment: I've not come across this particular scenario before, but try `Console.WriteLine("the status");` and see if that does what you need.

Comment: The usual way to do this to use [StandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx), but I'm not familiar with how you could interact with this in php.

Comment: @GlenThomas I tried Console.WriteLine("Executed A"); is not working.

Comment: Does $output contain anything at all or its just blank?

Comment: @Glen Thomas its black

Comment: Can you try `start /wait MyApp args` to see if your code is returning before output has happened?

Comment: Just go to properties and choose output type = console application. The form still will be opened and you can write messages on console as well. This question is a duplicate of a duplicate and has been asked for years.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you're asking. A console program can only "return" an integer value. But of course it can also write text to stdout. The latter _might_ work, but it depends on how PHP works and you didn't include the [tag:php] on your post, so many of the people reading your question have no idea how PHP would receive output sent to stdout. What part of this question are you asking about? Do you want to know how to write to stdout? Or do you want to know how to get PHP to _read_ from a program's stdout?

Comment: @Peter Duniho I want to know how to write to stdout

Comment: See marked duplicate.